# php - shifting variable value by if else simplification

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to make something like this to my variable data value...

```
$maxvalue = 0;
$basevalue = 0;
if($basevalue == 0) {$maxvalue = 0;}
else if ($basevalue == 1) {$maxvalue = 884;}
else if ($basevalue == 2) {$maxvalue = 1819;}
else if ($basevalue == 3) {$maxvalue = 2839;}
```

and so on.. i believe there is no exact computation on how the $maxvalue shifts as the basevalue increase. Can someone suggest me a simplier way to do this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have more values? Maybe there is a pattern.

Comment: im not sure.. its really weird. here's 1-10 values.. 1-884, 2-1819, 3-2839, 4-3978, 5-5270, 6-6749, 7-8449, 8-10404, 9-12648, 10-15215 ... the fact that its until 100.. lol

Comment: so still no luck getting the pattern? =_=

Comment: As a matter of fact I do.

Comment: Did it work? Or did you put every value in an array after all?

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for the help. But also i managed to get the formula as well ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$maxvalues = array(0, 884, 1819, 2839, ...);
$maxvalue  = $maxvalues[$basevalue];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a pattern, almost like a faculty, but also with some other calculations. All numbers are multiples of 17. The following function returns the numbers you provided, so I think it might work for the higher numbers too:

```
function getMaxValue($base)
{
    // Factor of $base = 51 + $base^2 + Factor($base - 1). You
    // could solve that in a recursion, but a loop is generally better.
    $factor = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $base; $i++)
      $factor += 51 + ($i * $i);
    return $factor * 17;
}

// Test
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    echo "$i -- " . getMaxValue($i) . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that prevented me putting all of them in an array..

```
$maxvalue = 17/6*(2*($basevalue*$basevalue*$basevalue)+3
($basevalue*$basevalue)+307*$basevalue);
```

Thanks for all the help